# Rails instance variable join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is so simple but it's been ages since I needed this.
I have the following code

```
<% @miniature.minisets.each do |miniset| %>
   <%= link_to miniset.name, miniset %>
<% end %>
```

It outputs `Minisetname Minisetname Minisetname` etc

I want it to output `Minisetname, Minisetname, Minisetname` with commas.

I've tried to include `.join(", ")` but can't find the right place to put it. Do I also need to use `.map` instead of `.each`?

Ignominy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way that ought to work:

```
<%= @miniature.minisets.map { |miniset| link_to miniset.name, miniset }.join(", ").html_safe %>
```

Comment: This will return escaped links. You need to add `.html_safe` at the end (there are multiple ways how to set that string should not be escaped).

Comment: Note that I haven't tested this. Because of the way `Array#join` works, you might also have to explicitly mark the result HTML-safe: http://makandracards.com/makandra/954-don-t-mix-array-join-and-string-html_safe

Comment: That's instead of having a `each do` and therefore doesn't need an `end` tag right? For some reason that's breaking and showing html.

Comment: It doesn't need an end tag. The problem is the thing I thought of afterwards (and Lukas also mentioned): the HTML safety attribute gets removed during the join. Since `link_to` output should be sanitized already, just adding `.html_safe` should suffice in this case. The linked article discusses the issue more generally.